# Something like isFirst/isLast in PlayFramework 2.x Templates

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, templating

I am iterating a variable like this in PlayFramework 2.1.2

```
  @for(l: Lang <- Globals.availableLangs) {
    @if(l != ctx.lang) {
      <a ng-click="i18nManager.changeLanguage('@l.code')" prevent-default href="#">@Messages("global.footer.langChange." + l.code.replace("-","_"))</a>
    }
  }
```

I want to add `&nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;` between each "`a`" generated by loop. In PlayFramework 1.x we had `_isFirst` `_isLast` for `{list}` tag. How can I do this in Play Framework 2.x?

I need something like this:

```
  @var first = true
  @for(l: Lang <- Globals.availableLangs) {
    @if(!first) { &nbsp;&middot;&nbsp; @first = false}
    @if(l != ctx.lang) {
      <a ng-click="i18nManager.changeLanguage('@l.code')" prevent-default href="#">@Messages("global.footer.langChange." + l.code.replace("-","_"))</a>
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to the first and last element you can always use `head` and `last` found in the [Immutable List API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). And to avoid iterating over the head again, only iterate over the `tail` of the list.

```
@defining(@Globals.availableLangs.filterNot(_ == ctx.lang).head){ l =>
  <a ng-click="i18nManager.changeLanguage('@l.code')" prevent-default href="#">@Messages("global.footer.langChange." + l.code.replace("-","_"))</a>  
}
@for(l: Lang <- Globals.availableLangs.filterNot(_ == ctx.lang).tail) {
      &nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;
      <a ng-click="i18nManager.changeLanguage('@l.code')" prevent-default href="#">@Messages("global.footer.langChange." + l.code.replace("-","_"))</a>   
}
```

**EDIT** Misread your intent, updated to match it.

**EDIT2** Added filter to eliminate conditional check.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I can use all features of scala on templates! I've completely forgotten about that. I modified my code like this and it does what I want now:       `@for(l: Lang <- Globals.availableLangs.filterNot(_ == ctx.lang)) {
        @if(Globals.availableLangs.filterNot(_ == ctx.lang).head != l) {
          &nbsp;&middot;&nbsp;
        }
        <a ng-click="i18nManager.changeLanguage('@l.code')" prevent-default href="#">@Messages("global.footer.langChange." + l.code.replace("-","_"))</a>
      }` If you edit your post with this code, I'd like to mark it as answered.

Comment: @UmutBenzer I updated my code to use the filter like you have, but I would still use the head/tail method rather than filter the list to check for the head every iteration.